# jQuery: add css to parent

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="control-group">
            <input value="" id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="E-mail"/> <span class="help-inline"></span>
          </div>
```

And the follow jQuery:

```
var input = $(this);

$.getJSON("/email", { email: data }, function(json){
                if(json.valid == true){
                    input.parent().addClass("success");
                }
            });
```

How can I add the class 'success' to the div control-group? Also, how can I add content to the help-inline span?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code is alright , to adding class to `.control-group` is right

and to adding content to `.help-inline`, you can use `.next()` like...

```
input.next(".help-inline").html("your text");
```

or...

```
input.next(".help-inline").html("your text").parent().addClass("success");
```

**Full code :**

```
var input = $(this);

$.getJSON("/email", { email: data }, function(json){
                if(json.valid == true){
                    input.parent().addClass("success");
                    input.next(".help-inline").html("your text");
                }
});
```